# mouse as vanishing point

Tags: jquery, performance, css, geometry

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay4rE/) you can see my implementation.

It basically works as itended, but there are some spots where the angle changes abruptly and not smoothly. Play with your mouse and find out. (When X-Position of the mouse is about the X-Position of the vanishing Line). Also I don't get why the vanishing Line is not following the mouse farther than 45°.

```
lineRad = Math.asin(Math.sin(vertDist / mouseLineDist));

lineRad = (mouseX - lineX) >= 0 ? lineRad : -lineRad  + Math.PI;
lineRad = (mouseY - lineY) >= 0 ? lineRad : -lineRad;
```

This could be the origin of the jumps, but I am not sure.

I just checked this under Firefox. It seems to have major performance issues.
So this prototype works in Chrome. Any Suggestions for performance and browser compatibility are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the function atan2, it solves your problem perfectly in one line:

```
horDist = (mouseX - lineX);
vertDist = (mouseY - lineY);

lineRad = Math.atan2(vertDist, horDist);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay4rE/1/)

Also, probably you will get better perfomance setting the transform origin as apropiate, instead of setting an aditional translateY